# Increment pagination value Scraping+Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a dinamically generated website using Selenium+Scrapy.

I have scraped the items from the first page successfully but when I try to get to the next page, seems that the browser generated for selenium is always rquesting the same page.

What I'm trying:
1.-Execute parse function to extract the first page data.
2.-Once the extraction is finished, search for next button and get the href attribute.
3.-Call again the same function sending the new url.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class IndeedSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "indeed"
    allowed_domains = ["es.indeed.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://es.indeed.com/jobs?q&l=Barcelona"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_jobs)
    
    def parse_jobs(self, response):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("https://es.indeed.com/jobs?q&l=Barcelona")
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        offersnames=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td/div/h2/span")

        for i in range(len(offersnames)):
            yield {
                "name": offersnames[i].text
            }

        next_page_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pagination-list > li:last-child > a")
        next_page_url=next_page_element.get_attribute("href")
        if next_page_url:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_jobs)

        driver.quit()
```

Comment: From  https://www.website.com/list?q&l=Barcelona&source=SC, I'm getting HTTP 404 - File not found

Comment: @F.Hoque updated, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of scrapy.Request, you should be using click event. The general structure should be; wait for the page to be fully loaded; wait for button to apprear on the page. Then click on the button. Then get the updated page, something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
btn = driver.find_element_by_id('input-search')
btn.click()
time.sleep(2) 
print(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
```

I havnt ran code but something on these lines.